# Is it possible to connect to a Test Resource in HP ALM as a database?

Tags: quality-center

I know how I can connect to an Excel sheet as a database using the ADO objects, but as it is, I need to download the spreadsheet from Test Resources and store it locally.  How can I connect to the spreadsheet in ALM **without** downloading it from Test Resources?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is available on the network you might be able to set up an DSN to use with and ODBC connection that you can use with the ADO objects.  Here are a couple references that might help

[Connect to Excel using ODBC in C#](http://www.microsoft-csharp-tutorials.com/post/2013/02/20/Connect-to-Excel-using-ODBC-in-C) - a basic example in c#
[Unable to create DSN for Microsoft Office System Driver on 64-bit versions of Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2721825/EN-US) - some details around working around the 32/64 bit differences ins ODBC drivers for office.